# character device file (rtai_shm) disappears under runlevel=5 in fedora9 (exists when runlevel=3)

Tags: fedora, devices, udev, reboot, runlevel

I am trying to run Realtime (RTAI) on my Linux Fedora 9 machine. For that, it is needed to have a character device file, named `rtai_shm`, in `/dev`, that takes care of shared memory. I have made this file using the command `mknod -m 666 /dev/rtai_shm c 10 254`.

If I boot with runlevel 3 (i.e. `initdefault == 3` in `/etc/inittab` file), then `/dev/rtai_shm` exists, and I can perfectly print:

```
$ ls -l /dev/rt*
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root  10, 254 Sep 23  2014 /dev/rtai_shm
```

*However*, when I boot with runlevel 5 (i.e. `initdefault == 5` in `/etc/inittab`), then I cannot see `/dev/rtai_shm anymore`, and `ls` does not list any file with that name. Accordingly, my original server which should communicate with RTAI fails to respond. The problem persists in both GUI and terminal interface, and even when I login as root.

I would highly appreciate any help or hint on this!